# add scroll bar to table body

Tags: html, css

I want to do this as easily as possible with out any additional libraries.

In my very long table I want to add a scrollbar to the `<tbody>` tag  so that the head is always visible but it wont work. can you please help.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Hpx4L/

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody style="overflow-y:scroll; height:100px;"> <!-- wont work -->
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A table cannot scroll. You need to do some trickery to get a scrolling body. For example; a wrapping div with scroll and an absolute positioned table header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345390/tabletbody-scrollable and many others

Comment: yes I did -  I am currently doing it in that method and its not great, so I wanted to ask for help

Comment: or this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5662431/2379542

Answer (score 86, accepted):

you can wrap the content of the `<tbody>` in a scrollable `<div>` :

html

```
....
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="scrollit">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          ...
```

css

```
.scrollit {
    overflow:scroll;
    height:100px;
}
```

see my jsfiddle, forked from yours: http://jsfiddle.net/VTNax/2/

Comment: I can't believe I wasted hours trying to fix my broken layout as a result of using `<tbody style="display: block;">`, when the solution was as simple as putting `<tbody>` inside a scrollable `<div>`. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @braican Doesn't seem to work for me, can you take a look please.

Comment: I seem to have alignment issues

Comment: How does this accomodate for different browser sizes?

Comment: @myol because the inner table is independent of the outer table, you may need to set an explicit width for the appropriate columns. You'll notice in my jsfiddle that the first <td> element in both the parent and child tables have a width of 200 set. Unfortunately, since the two tables aren't technically related at all, this is the most foolproof way to ensure the columns match up.

Comment: @sparkyShorts there shouldn't be any issues with different browser sizes (though I'd imagine some work would be needed at the phone size). Assuming your tables are set up to respond to differing browser sizes, everything should cascade appropriately.

Comment: `table > div > tbody` is invalid HTML syntax

Comment: How does this affect accessibility?

Comment: This is no longer a semantically correct table and if that's the case you shouldn't bother using tables at all

Answer (score 16):

These solutions often have issues with the header columns aligning with the body columns, and may not work properly when resizing.  I know you didn't want to use an additional library, but if you happen to be using jQuery, this one is really small.  It supports fixed header, footer, column spanning (colspan), horizontal scrolling, resizing, and an optional number of rows to display before scrolling starts.

[jQuery.scrollTableBody (GitHub)](https://github.com/nheldman/jquery.scrollTableBody)

As long as you have a table with proper `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and (optional) `<tfoot>`, all you need to do is this:

```
$('table').scrollTableBody();
```

Comment: This is the only solution I could find that did not require screwing up the HTML/CSS of the table. Thanks!

Comment: @Sevin7 If you look at the code for this jQuery plugin, it is actually adding extra html / css to your table.  So it's screwing up the html / css for you, rather than you having to do it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you are adding your `<tbody>` tag before `<td>` in table you cannot print any data without `<td>`.

So for that you have to make a `<div>` say `#header` with `position: fixed;`

```
 header
 {
      position: fixed;
 }
```

make another `<div>` which will act as `<tbody>`

```
tbody
{
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Now your header is fixed and the body will scroll. And the header will remain there.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to wrap a table under any **div**:

```
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
tbody{
      display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```