# Scroll not working in HTML table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something on the lines of [add scroll bar to table body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450861/add-scroll-bar-to-table-body/24100774#24100774) to add scroll to my table, but it doesn't seem to work.
Here's my layout(http://jsfiddle.net/cvvrjtdd/5/):

```
<div align="center">
    <table class="sampleTable">
        <tr>
            <th class="centerAlign" colspan="3">
                <b>HEADER</b>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="centerAlign">COLUMN 1</th>
            <th class="centerAlign">COLUMN 2</th>
            <th class="centerAlign">COLUMN 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody class="scroll">
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    <a href="google.com">DATA</a>
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="centerAlign">
                    DATA
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

And my css

```
table.sampleTable {
  border: 0;
  width: 60%;
  height: 90%;
  display: block;
}

td.centerAlign, th.centerAlign {
  text-align: center;
}

tbody.scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simple can't to paste any DOM elements between the table rows.
Try to use `tbody`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvvrjtdd/4/)

Comment: Thanks, td.centerAlign doesn't seem to work anymore though. http://jsfiddle.net/cvvrjtdd/7/ Is it related ?

Comment: no, it's work. it align the text in the cells by center. Try to set column widths.